# Is it possible to convert a .exe file to .py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, executable

I created an executable file (**.exe** file) of a python script.

I lost the folder with the original python script (also no backups), due to disk formatting.

By chance I got its executable file on the drive.

**Can I *re-convert* it to the python script?**

Comment: You may want to see https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160/how-do-you-reverse-engineer-an-exe-compiled-with-pyinstaller.

Comment: It's not possible to restore code from .exe artifact

Comment: Whart does "formation of the computer" means? Please use a dictionary to choose your words (I am also a non-native English speaker, and I use a dictionary every day). So [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52167649/edit) your question to improve it

Comment: I highly doubt it you probably need some sort of third party software

Comment: I didn't understood what you want to say...@theJ

Comment: BTW, losing source code is a mistake everyone makes once as a newbie (for me it was punched cards). Next time and for the rest of your developer's life, you'll learn to never lose it (e.g. by using version control and having backups).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, what you dream of is called a [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler), and cannot really exist (in a reliable and systematic way) for Python (and for most programming languages and their implementations, because they are not [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity)). Consider that your Python source code is lost (but see also [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/161): analyzing your executable would take a lot of time, a lot of skills, so is practically not worth the effort).

Learn to use a [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system (for your future source code). I recommend [`git`](http://git-scm.com/). Make backups. Even better, publish your software with a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) license (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/) or elsewhere) while you are developping it.

You could also pay a lot of money (perhaps thousands of € or US$) to ask some specialized companies to recover data (hopefully also your lost source code) from your crashed disk drive.  This is usually not worth the money.

Comment: It means, python executable file cannot be easily hacked? Meaning of say, it will be very difficult for someone to distribute a cracked version of it.... Am I right?

Comment: You don't define what `be hacked` means, and what `a cracked version` is

Comment: I think, Till the software is not hacked, a crack version cannot be build....And my meaning of question is that, can it be cracked easily?

Comment: What does "software be cracked easily" means to you? I feel you have  a naive vision about software. Probably, nobody cares about your software, so you should not be scared of these things. Why would anyone want "to hack" or "to crack" your executable? Except perhaps you, nobody cares about it or know that it exists!

Comment: @ChiragJain, it's easy to _disassemble_ Python code, even though tools to _decompile_ it aren't freely available for recent versions. It is thus easy for people (at least, people with reverse engineering skills) to build modified versions of Python applications distributed as executables -- I've done so myself.